# Is it possible to configure device channels for team site

Tags: mobile, team-sites, responsive, device-channel

I am trying to configure device channels for one of my existing sites created using Team site template and it is not working (no UI difference from device to device). It is working well if I create a new publishing site however I want to achieve the same for my existing team site. I have deactivated the mobile browser feature and activated the publishing site and site collection features but still not working.

Is it at all possible to configure device channels for team sites? If yes, please share the steps. If not, is there any alternative solution for this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Device channels are available only for Publishing sites. See more about [Device Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862343.aspx). But if you activate the **Publishing features** in team site and use **Pages library** for all pages instead of Site Pages (to have page layouts for each page), then the site should adapt the responsiveness.

Comment: Since it is an existing site with lot of pages, we can't move them to Pages library. Instead we have written a web part that looks at user-agent and registers a script on the page to show/hide elements on page as per the device.